# obtain a value from object using its class member function

Tags: php, oop

`var_dump($request)` gives following output

```
object(Core)#7 (1) {
  ["_data":"Core":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["uid"]=>
    string(7) "1700451"
  }
}
```

The core class is as follows-

```
Class Core{
     __construct(){

     }
 public function __get($name) {
    if (!$this->_data[$name]) {
        return null;
    }
        return $this->_data[$name];
    }    
}
```

How do i call the `__get` method to obtain the uid from the `$request` obj.

Please do not suggest changes in the code.I just want a way to get the uid from the $request variable.I am weak in OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__get` enables a "magic interface" to object properties. In this case, all you need to do is:

```
$request->uid
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get.

Comment: but in my code the the __get function is explicitly defined in a core class..will it work?